# Compilation error when Implementing twice a generic interface, with a base and a derived type

Tags: vb.net, generics, interface, compiler-errors

I am trying to implement twice a generic interface, once using a base type and once with a more derived type. This works if the implementing class B is not generic itself, but it fails for class C, which is generic, with a type constraint.

Error given is: "Cannot implement interface 'iB(Of TInterface)' because its implementation could conflict with the implementation of another implemented interface 'iB(Of iA)' for some type arguments."

I think class C should compile just as fine as class B, given the fact that TInterface derives from iAA, and I can't see why the compiler would throw an error. Defect in the compiler? Can someone please advice?

Code follows:

```
Interface iA
End Interface

Interface iAA
    Inherits iA
End Interface

Interface iB(Of T)
    ReadOnly Property GetValue As T 
End Interface


Class B
    Implements iB(Of iA)
    Implements iB(Of iAA)

    ReadOnly Public Property GetAA As iAA  Implements iB(Of iAA).GetValue
        Get
            Return Nothing
        End Get
    End Property

    ReadOnly Public Property GetA As iA Implements iB(Of iA).GetValue
        Get
            Return GetAA
        End Get
    End Property
End Class


Class C(Of TInterface As iAA)
    Implements iB(Of iA)
    Implements iB(Of TInterface) ' This gives a compilation error

    Public ReadOnly Property GetAA As TInterface Implements iB(Of TInterface).GetValue
        Get
            Return Nothing
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property GetA As iA Implements iB(Of iA).GetValue
        Get
            Return GetAA
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```